# C# localization. Problems with mixing of Left-to-Right words with Right-to-left words in the same sentence

Tags: c#, localization, arabic

I'm looking on how to solve problems while mixing words that require right-to-left(like arabic) reading and left-to-right words (like English).

The problem we encounter is that when inserting a LTR word inside a sentence meant to be read in RTL (inserting an English word inside an Arabic sentence for eg): the English text is correctly written from left to right,but the problem is that the Arabic part that comes after ends-up on the wrong side.
The context of this is that the program I'm working on needs for example to insert some IDs or object identifiers that need to be remained in English but inserted in a localized sentence (Arabic in this case).

To illustrate an example, let's say the RTL words are in lowercase and LTR words are in uppercase.

My desired output would be:

```
abc ABC efg
```

but we instead get

```
abc ABC gfe
```

The only way to get the correct output is to insert the unicode markers (LTR for left-to-right, the PDF for Pop-Directional-Formatting that will mark the end of it) before and after the LTR text :

```
abc {LTR} ABC {PDF} efg
```

This is a solution that can be used, but I was wondering if there was not an easier way to handle this, automatically? The RTL words are in the resource files, while the English parts are -usually- coming from Db calls. 
Any past experience on how to handle this particular scenario?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark: have you tried using {RTL} instead of {PDF}...?

Comment: I've not tried, although I think it will most likely work. The main question is rather: is there a way to automatically handle this mix of "read flow words"? Inserting {LTR} {PDF} or {LTR} {RTL} manually is pretty tedious and not really maintainable