# How to localize argument placeholders for right-to-left languages

Tags: xcode, localization, right-to-left

I'm trying to add placeholders in my string templates for Arabic, but I'm having a hard time making it work.

For example, I have this English version:

`"shortcut.reminder.mins" = "You will be notified in %d minutes";`

When converting this to Arabic, injecting the `%d` in the string breaks the string in the editor. Here is what it should look like replacing the variable with underscores:

`"shortcut.reminder.mins" = "سيتم إعلامك خلال _____ دقيقة";`

However, trying to replace the underscores with the intended `%d`, it breaks the sentence because I'm trying to inject a left-to-right phrase in a right-to-left sentence:

`"shortcut.reminder.mins" = "سيتم إعلامك خلال %d دقيقة";`

Is there a language-specific placeholder I'm supposed to use, or do I always use English placeholders in the localized string? How do I not break the sentence by mixing right/left languages?

Comment: Can you have a look at these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031315/c-sharp-localization-problems-with-mixing-of-left-to-right-words-with-right-to?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172297/string-format-problem-in-concatenating-left-to-right-languages-with-right-to-lef?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207486/right-to-left-languages-and-programming-problems?rq=1